# Linear regresion of rectangular table against one set of values

Tags: r

I have a rectangular table with three variables: country, year and inflation. I already have all the descriptives I can have, now I need to do some analytics, and figured that I should do some linear regression against a target country. The best idea I had was to create a new variable called inflation.in.country.x and loop through the inflation of x in this new column but that seems somehow unclean solution.

How to get a linear regression of a rectangular data table? The structure is like this:

```
> dat %>% str
'data.frame':   1196 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Country.Name: Factor w/ 31 levels "Albania","Armenia",..: 9 8 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 19 ...
 $ year        : chr  "1967" "1967" "1967" "1967" ...
 $ inflation   : num  1.238 8.328 3.818 0.702 1.467 ...
```

I want to take Armenia inflation as dependent variable and Albania as independent to get a linear regression. It is possible without transforming the data and keeping the years coherent?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

One way is to spread your data table using `Country.Name` as key:

```
dat.spread <- dat %>% spread(key="Country.Name", value="inflation")
dat.spread %>% str
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  31 variables:
 $ year              : chr  "1967" "1968" "1969" "1970" ...
 $ Albania           : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Armenia           : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Brazil            : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 [...]
```

But that forces you to transform the data which may seem undesirable. Afterwards, you can simply use `cbind` to do the linear regression against all countries:

```
lm(cbind(Armenia, Brazil, Colombia, etc...) ~ Albania, data = dat.spread)
```